# Map separate button to separate CSS file to change background image of my page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to change the background of my page using angular f/w by calling the different CSS files on click of different button on the same page.

**CSS1.css**

```
body {
     background-image: url("./Images/mg.jpg");
}
```

**CSS2.css**

```
body {
     background-image: url("./Images/mg.jpg");
}
```

In the html file i am trying to create 2 buttons such that on click of button1, CSS1.css file will be called and on click of button2, CSS2.css file will be called.

I am trying to access a CSS file by creating an ID to the button and mapping script function function to it but i am getting some runtime error

**HTML File**

```
<button type="button" id="button1" onclick="myFunction()">background1</button>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="CSS1.css" id="theme">
```

**Script file**

```
function myFunction()
{   
document.getElementById("button1")= document.getElementById("theme");
}
```

Can you please lemme know what am I doing wrong here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

stylesheet links load the stylesheet right away. You don't need custom Javascript to apply it.

To achieve the effect you want you can remove the link tags and modify the function like that:

```
function myFunction() {   
    document.body.style.background = "url('./Images/mg.jpg')";
}
```

Comment: How can i achieve this in angular4 .Could you please tell?

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementById()` method returns the element that has the `ID` attribute with the specified value.

The left side `document.getElementById("button1")` returns a value , the right side also returns a value. This is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this this:

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS1.css" id="theme">

<button type="button" (click)="myFunction('CSS1.css')"> background1 </button>
<button type="button" (click)="myFunction('CSS2.css')"> background2 </button>
```

*Tip: Note that I changed your `onclick` to `(click)`. I notice that one of your tags on your question is `angular`. If you are using angular, then you should use this attribute instead of `onclick`.*

**TypeScript**

```
myFunction(sheet: string) {
    document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
```

Comment: This is the error i am getting, also the buttons are not added successfully. And i need to find the way to use different style sheet i.e css file on click of button

Comment: Error: 10% building modules 0/1 modules 1 active ...ment1\themeproj\src\app\app.module.tsERROR in src/app/screen/screen.component.ts(11,3): error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
src/app/screen/screen.component.ts(39,14): error TS1005: ';' expected.
src/app/screen/screen.component.ts(42,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

Comment: I didn't realize you were using typescript. I am editing now for you.

Comment: You cannot use a declaration of `function` before a function in typescript.

Comment: Actually i want to change the css file on click of buton in angular4.

Comment: You can refer this link http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Change-Style-Sheet-Using-Tutorial-CSS-Swap-Stylesheet. I want the same thing in Angular4.

Comment: In which file i should write this <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS1.css" id="theme">